# Interesting usage from BBC .... "a visit that will see someone do something"

Tags: relative-clauses

Below is the news from the BBC web site:

> The Duke and Duchess of Cambridge are in France on a two-day official visit **that will also see them attend** the Six Nations rugby match between France and Wales, and meet survivors of the terrorist attacks in Paris and Nice.

Isn't there a problem with the relative clause in this sentence as it says "a visit that will also see them attend...".

Who sees them attend the match? The visit? How can a visit see someone do something.

Comment: *See* has many more definitions than just "to perceive with the eyes".  For example, [2 c: to be the setting or time of *"the last fifty years have seen a sweeping revolution in science"*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)

Comment: You will often find **see** used that way, for example, "The 20th century saw two world wars".  The subject of the verb **see** is typically a period of time or something which occurs over a period of time, not a person. *The second half of the game saw three yellow cards given out.*

Answer (score 1):

In this context the verb to see has the meaning of

`to witness`

or

```
to be the occasion when
```

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see